# Unity3d Camera is not rendaring game after set targetTexture for camera

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I am using this code for take screen shots from the game and save to hard drive. Screen shot perfectly saved in to disk. The problem is after taking screen shot, my camera does not render game anymore. Camera stil have that screen shot. But I noticed that game running normally. 
Im using Unity 5.6.0b4

Here is my code (Sorry about my English :D). Pleace help to solve this

```
using UnityEngine;

public class Screenshot : MonoBehaviour
{
    int resWidth = Screen.width*4; 
    int resHeight = Screen.height*4;

    public Camera SS_Camera;
    int scale = 1;
    bool takeShot = false;
    RenderTexture renderTexture;


    void Update()
    {
        if (Input.GetKey(KeyCode.Return))
        {
            takeShot = true;
            if (takeShot)
            {
                takeShot = false;
                int resWidthN = resWidth * scale;
                int resHeightN = resHeight * scale;
                RenderTexture rt = new RenderTexture(resWidthN, resHeightN, 24);
                SS_Camera.targetTexture = rt;

                TextureFormat tFormat;
                tFormat = TextureFormat.RGB24;

                Texture2D screenShot = new Texture2D(resWidthN, resHeightN, tFormat, false);
                SS_Camera.Render();

                RenderTexture.active = rt;
                screenShot.ReadPixels(new Rect(0, 0, resWidthN, resHeightN), 0, 0);
                SS_Camera.targetTexture = null;
                RenderTexture.active = null;

                byte[] bytes = screenShot.EncodeToPNG();
                string filename = @"D:\Gameply_Screenshot001.png";

                System.IO.File.WriteAllBytes(filename, bytes);


            }
        }
    }


}
```

Comment: SS_Camera camera is my main camera. after taking screen shot the camera not working normal way. only shows captured image. but game runs

Comment: Only one. I assign Main camera to SS_Camera from ther Inspector